# Why is the object prefix converted to function argument?

Tags: c++, this

In the learncpp article about [the hidden this pointer](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/the-hidden-this-pointer/), the author mentioned that the compiler converts the object prefix to an argument passed by address to the function.

In the example:

```
simple.setID(2);
```

Will be converted to:

```
setID(&simple, 2); // note that simple has been changed from an object prefix to a function argument!
```

Why does the compiler do this? I've tried searching other documentation about it but couldn't find any. I've asked other people but they say it is a mistake or the compiler doesn't do that.

I have a second question on this topic. Let's go back to the example:

```
simple.setID(2); //Will be converted to setID(&simple, 2);
```

If the compiler converts it, won't it just look exactly like a function that has a name of `setID` and has two parameters?

```
void setID(MyClass* obj, int id) {
     return;
}


int main() {
    MyClass simple;
    simple.setID(2); //Will be converted to setID(&simple, 2);
    setID(&simple, 2);
    
}
```

Line 6 and 7 would look exactly the same.

Comment: Note the word _"hidden"_ in the link.  This is an implementation detail and should not affect how you write your code.  The signature of the method does not include that which is _"hidden"_.

Comment: C++ at present does not support [Uniform Function Call Syntax (UFCS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Function_Call_Syntax).

Comment: `simple.setID(2);` is **not** converted to `setID(&simple, 2);`.  That "conversion" is simply a metaphor to help you imagine what a C++ compiler is doing.  If you are asking why this metaphor is truly happening, it isn't.

Comment: If you read "will be converted" to "might be converted" or even "could be converted" or even "was once converted back in the days where C++ was compiled to C with the CFront compiler" then that might be helpful for you. Really your question is not a C++ question at all, but a C++ compiler question. Not sure why it's been silently downvoted though. I'm going to fix that. Have an upvote.

Comment: The author is describing what happens using an *analogy* - which isn't specifying what compilers actually do. As to why .... imagine you do `object1.foo()` and `object2.foo()` which, in both cases, calls a member function named `ObjectType::foo()`. Somehow information identifying which object ( `object1`, `object2`, or something else) needs to be passed (e.g. so the function can access members of *that* object), but the function signature doesn't provide it.  The way this is done is via the `this` pointer (and the compiler takes care of whatever magic is needed to make that happen).

Comment: @Peter so what the author mentioned doesn't actually happen, the compiler doesn't actually do that. Let's say I call `a.foo();`; in the background, it will call `a.foo(&a);` because there is a hidden parameter right?

Comment: @user19528914 It will not call `a.foo(&a)` because there is no such function to call.   The implementation (typically the compiler in this case) does what it likes, as long as the non-static member function can access the object it was called for using the `this` pointer - the standard does not dictate how the implementation achieves that. Different compilers can (and do) use completely different mechanisms. In a class hierarchy, `this` for a derived class often has different value than the `this` for a base class - even when referring to the same object - which makes your analogy a poor fit.

Answer (score 1):

> object prefix to an argument passed by address to the function

This refers to how implementations use to translate it to machine code (but they could do it any other way)

> Why does the compiler do this?

In some way, you need to be able to refer to the object in the called member function, and one way is to just handle it like an argument.

> If the compiler converts it, won't it just look exactly like a function that has a name of `setID` and has two parameters?

If you have this code:

```
struct Test {
    int v = 0;
    Test(int v ) : v(v) {

    }
    void test(int a) {
        int v = this->v;
        int r = a;
    } 
};

void test(Test* t, int a) {
    int v = t->v;
    int r = a + v;

}

int main() {
    Test a(2);
    a.test(1);
    test(&a, 1);

    return 0;
}
```

gcc-12 will create this assembly code (for x86 and if optimizations are turned off):

```
Test::Test(int) [base object constructor]:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-12], esi
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax], edx
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
Test::test(int a):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-24], rdi
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-28], esi
// int v = this->v;
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], eax
// int r = a;
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-28]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], eax
// end of function
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
test(Test* t, int a):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-24], rdi
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-28], esi
// int v = t->v;
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], eax
// int r = a + v;
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rbp-28]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        add     eax, edx
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], eax
// end of function
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        lea     rax, [rbp-4]
        mov     esi, 2
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    Test::Test(int) [complete object constructor]
// a.test(1);
        lea     rax, [rbp-4]
        mov     esi, 1
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    Test::test(int)
// test(&a, 1);
        lea     rax, [rbp-4]
        mov     esi, 1
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    test(Test*, int)
// end of main
        mov     eax, 0
        leave
        ret
```

So the machine code generated with no optimizations, looks identical for `test(&a, 1)` and `a.test(1)`.  And that's what the statement refers to.

But again that is an implementation detail how the compiler translates c++ to machine code, and not related to c++ itself.